# does local volatility make any sense when I only focus on vanilla option?

Tags: options, local-volatility

can someone explain me the usage of local volatility? details will be appreciated. Is it of any importance when I now are doing market-making? Please do not laugh at me as I am totally new in this field.

Answer (score 1):

Local volatility trats volatility as a function of price (St) and time (t), considering volatility constant.

It means that you are building a volatility surface depending on price and time.

What you are doing is given a certain value of volatility, what will be the price in Xdays long, or viceversa.

If you are dong market making with plain vanilla options, I will advice you to use Stochastic Volatility models.

Comment: So when do we need local volatility？

Comment: You will use it when the product you are valuating is not path dependant. In other words, when you "know" in advance the volatility.

Comment: My idea is that local volatility is a shortcut when the volatility surface doesn’t move too much in time. It is like we were taking the average volatility of a stochastic volatility model, and in some sense this is the central idea of Derman-Kani (1998) paper: local volatility is the risk neutral expectation of stochastic volatility when option is at strike price at maturity.

Comment: @arodrisa so local volatility can be used to price vanilla options?

Comment: @franic so how can we do with local volatility? Pricing what?

Comment: @Tim Yes, it can.

Comment: anecdotical evidence would lead me to conclude that local volatility quite often gives the “wrong” hedge even with vanilla products. Anyway, it’s still a useful shortcut

Comment: Totally agree. In fact my experience tells me to use local volatility as an initial point of my valuations.